# Mapping and converting between class lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mapping

I have a query retrieving a number of users in which users may be subscribed to multiple UserTeamNotifications containing an Id and Name. I'm trying to get a list of these users with a list of the notifications they are subscribed to. Such that my User.cs class will have a list of NotificationTeam objects.

```
string sql = @"
SELECT
    u.UserId,
    u.UserName,
    tn.TeamId AS NoticationTeamId,
    tn.TeamName AS NoticationTeamName
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Teams tu ON tu.TeamId = u.TeamId
LEFT JOIN UserTeamNotifications n ON n.UserId = u.UserId
LEFT JOIN Teams tn ON tn.TeamId = n.TeamId
";
            return connection.Connection.Query<DbUser>(sql)
                .GroupBy(u => u.UserId)
                .Select(u => UserMapper.Map(u.First(), u.Select(n => new DbTeamNotification
                {
                    TeamId = n.NotificationTeamId,
                    TeamName = n.NotificationTeamName
                }).ToList()))
                .ToList();
```

I'm having trouble mapping the TeamNotifications back to my controller however. With the error: Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SBIS.Data.DbObjects.DbTeamNotification>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SBIS.Models.Users.NotificationTeam>'. In the mapping below.

UserMapper.cs

```
    internal class UserMapper
    {
        public static User Map(DbUser source, List<DbTeamNotification> notifications)
        {
            return source == null ? null : new User(
                userId: source.UserId,
                name: source.UserName,
                notificationTeams: notifications
                );
        }
    }
```

User.cs

```
public sealed class User
{
    public User(long userId, string name, List<NotificationTeam> notificationTeams)
    {
        m_userId = userId;
        m_name = name;
        m_notificationTeams = notificationTeams;
    }

    public long UserId => m_userId;
    public string UserName => m_name;
    public List<NotificationTeam> NotificationTeams => m_notificationTeams;

    private readonly long m_userId;
    private readonly string m_name;
    private readonly List<NotificationTeam> m_notificationTeams;
}
```

DbUser.cs

```
internal sealed class DbUser
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public long NotificationTeamId { get; set; }
    public string NotificationTeamName { get; set; }
}
```

NotificationTeam.cs

```
public sealed class NotificationTeam
{
    public NotificationTeam(long teamId, string teamName)
    {
        m_teamId = teamId;
        m_teamName = teamName;
    }

    public long TeamId => m_teamId;
    public string TeamName => m_teamName;

    private readonly long m_teamId;
    private readonly string m_teamName;
}
```

DbTeamNotifications.cs

```
internal class DbTeamNotification
{
    public long TeamId { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: The `User` Class has `public List<NotificationTeam> NotificationTeams`. The `UserMapper` code is trying to assign `List<DbTeamNotification>` to `List<NotificationTeam>`.  The direct conversion between these two types is not possible that's why you are receiving this error. You might want to create mapper for NotificationTeam too..

Comment: Or loop thru `notifications` list in UserMapper code to create a new `List<NotificationTeam>` and then use it to create new User object.